# Google Play Billing Library 2.0 Acknowledge Purchase Time Limit for Test Purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library, acknowledgepurchase

I have been testing the the new Google billing library release.  The release notes state that "Purchases must be acknowledged within three days".

[Release notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes)

During testing, I noticed that if I don't acknowledge the purchase, within a few minutes, the purchase gets automatically refunded.

Is it the case that Google treats test orders differently and only allows a few minutes to acknowledge an order as opposed to 3 days or am I missing something?

Here is the code I am using to acknowledge the purchase.  PurchaseHolder is a class that holds the purchase and SKU along with a response code from my back end server

```
for (IABManager.PurchaseHolder pm : purchaseHolders){
    if(pm.getSku().equals(SKU)) {//found matching SKU
        if (pm.getActionResult() == IABManager.BillingActionResult.VALID_PURCHASE) {//valid purchase made
            if(!pm.getPurchase().isAcknowledged()) {//purchase not yet acknowledged
                iabManager.acknowledgePurchases(pm.getPurchase(), (billingResult) -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "AcknowledgedPurchaseResponse received from Google");
                    if(billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        unlockFeatures();
                    }
                });
            }else{
                unlockFeatures();
            }

        } else if (pm.getActionResult() == IABManager.BillingActionResult.NON_VALID_PURCHASE){
            lockFeatures();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "BILLING_ACTION_RESULT = " + pm.getActionResult() + " doing nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

...and the acknowledgePurchases method

```
public void acknowledgePurchases(Purchase purchase, AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener listener){

    AcknowledgePurchaseParams params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken()).build();

    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params, listener);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, from the Google Play Billing Library docs

> For purchases made by license testers, the acknowledgement window is shorter. Instead of three days, purchases are refunded and revoked if they are not acknowledged within five minutes

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#test_acknowledging_purchase_with_license_testers

Answer (score 2):

From the docs we can see that test purchases operate on a much shorter time scale to aid testing: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-renewals

If a one week subscription is renewed in 5 minutes, I imagine the 3 day purchase acknowledgement limit will be reduced to a couple minutes during development.

Comment: It seems logical that would be the case given that other time frames for test orders are condensed down to a matter of minutes.  I was just hoping google would have explicitly spelled it out or someone else who has tested this could confirm.

Comment: No worries, I was confused by that too. I'm not a huge fan of having to acknowledge/consume purchases but I can see the need for it. I just wish it was explained better in the docs.